# Rockshox reverb has tons of squish

Tags: dropper

A lot of times people talk about a 1cm squish to their dropper. However, mine is currently squishing all the way. Like, it goes all they say down if you just sit on it.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think the best solution is to sell this dropper for parts and buy another one that is not a Reverb. The cost of getting it serviced (which depends on your locality) may not be worth it, especially when you consider the possibility of this occurring again. Assuming this is an older generation one (not the latest C1 variant), the cost of keeping this one running just doesn’t look right, at least for me.

The Reverb’s design is flawed, allowing this defect to happen. A cartridge-style dropper such as a Brand-X or TransX is significantly more reliable, which in itself may be worth considering as a reason towards justifying an upgrade.